# Paypal - request multiple authorizations for an order

Tags: paypal

How do I create multiple authorizations for an order?

According to the docs:

> An order is valid for 29 days. During this period, you can request from one to ten or more authorizations to ensure the availability of funds. By default, you can make up to ten basic authorizations for each order. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/#overview

I tried creating an order with intent=authorize and then post with

https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/orderId/authorize

First it succeeded, yet when I want to create another authorization, it gave me error:

`issue":"ORDER_ALREADY_AUTHORIZED","description":"Order already authorized.If 'intent=AUTHORIZE' only one authorization per order is allowed." "debug_id":"47084737aefa3"`

So I canceled the original authorization and then tried to create a new one, still got the same error.

Then I changed intent=capture, it gave me

`"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"ACTION_DOES_NOT_MATCH_INTENT","description":"Order was created with an intent to 'CAPTURE'. Please use v2/checkout/orders/order_id/capture to complete the transaction or alternately Create an order with an intent of 'AUTHORIZE'."`

`"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"8c381672a8f1e"`

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is for v1/payments/orders, which are deprecated and very different in function and purpose from v2/checkout/orders.

v2/checkout/orders can only be captured a single time. An intervening authorization step is optional, if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!! I did try reauthorization but it's said only one reauthorization is allowed from day 4 to 29. The reason why I need reauthorization or multiple authorizations is that I need the authorization to stay in the honor period, since it guarantees the capture and otherwise the capture might fail(according to the docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/authorize-and-capture-payments/#overview)? 

Would you elaborate on "intervening authorization"? Do you mean to create a new order and get authorization from the customer again?

Comment: Sure, the capture might fail. And the reauthorization might fail. Anything might fail, there's no way around that. If an authorization or reauthorization does succeed, it gives you a 3 day honor period, that is all. Anything beyond that is not being reserved on the customer's funding source. If you don't specifically need those 3 day honor periods, don't use those authorizations, and proceed directly to capture.

Comment: I see. Thank you!!